# How do you remove old versions of Zapier Apps?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

While learning to develop a Zapier App with the CLI I created three different versions and used `zapier push` on them. Now I would like to remove the 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 versions so they no longer show up in the Zap editor but I can't find any information on how to do that. 
When I run `zapier versions` only 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 show up in the list but 1.0.0 still shows up in the Zap editor. Not sure what caused 1.0.0 to disappear from the version list.
I did try to deprecate the 1.0.1 version but that will take until July 3 to take effect. I also migrated from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 but that too had no effect in the Zap editor.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can just delete it from the Versions tab in the menu. Just click the gear icon next to the version you want to delete and scroll down until you see a delete option.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9kp0.png)

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

At this time, we don't allow devs to delete app versions because there's some unintended side effects if there were any users with zaps on that version. If you write into partners[at]zapier[dot]com, we'll be happy to double check user counts and delete unwanted versions for you!

​Let me know if you've got any other questions.